# Sequence of Predictions from HMMLearn

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

Im working along with this [documentation](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), but I can't figure out how to extract the sequence of predictions from the test data.

I have trained the model with `.fit(X_train)`, but the following:

`unseen_hidden_states = model.predict(X_test)`

Returns an array:

`[2 1 1 ..., 3 3 3]`

Which I dont know how to interpret or how to extract the predicted sequence from

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation:

> The inferred optimal hidden states can be obtained by calling
>   the `predict` method.

A results such as `[2, 1, 1, 3]` for a sequence `X_test = [x1, x2, x3, x4]` means that `x1` has most probably be generated by the hidden state `2`, `x2` by the hidden state `1`, `x3` by the hidden state `1`, and `x4` by the hidden state `3`.

If you want to read about the algorithm behind this, you can look for the Viterbi algorithm.

EDIT:

If you are looking for computing the likelihood of the data with respect to the model, you should have a look to the functions `score`, `_compute_log_likelihood`, or `score_samples`.

Comment: How do I get the actual value, as opposed to just hidden state its likely generated by?

Comment: @redress Check my edit. "Actual value" is quite unclear... I think you mean the likelihood of the data w.r.t. the model

Comment: If I’m predicting the stock market, how do I get the predicted price. That’s what I mean by actual value

Comment: @redress Your question seems similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258306/predicting-future-emissions-from-fitted-hmm-model
Please let me know if there is something you do not understand in that answer :)

Comment: `score_samples` returns 
```(-734802478.69610989, array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])) pred```

Comment: This still doesnt tell me the predicted price at each interval, only the hidden state